# In J2ME ,how to invoke/call a method by its name?

Tags: java-me

Is it possible in J2ME to call/invoke a method by its name.just like we have getDeclaredMethod in java .

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.reflect` package is available only in [CDC 1.1.2](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/index.html). If you're not on such configuration, you're out of luck. There is no way to invoke a method by name without reflection.

A workaround would be to create a map from strings (method names) to appropriate classes on which you can invoke the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can get is to instantiate a class by name using `Class.forName("com.class.ClassName").newInstance()` -- that will execute a parameterless constructor.